# PyCharm: Up arrow doesn't work in the console on readline prompt

Tags: pycharm, readline, pdb

I am trying to use PyCharm console with pdb, IPython, ipdb and other software relying on [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library. The console software use this library to provide command history and autocompletion. When you press up arrow you get the previous command.

However for some reason PyCharm console does not work as expected and pressing up arrow actually moves cursor to the previous row, instead of correctly doing the last command action.

[image]

Is there a way to configure PyCharm console to behave like a proper terminal and have this working correctly?

Answer (score -1):

To confirm this is supported and works well for me with pycharm 4.5 and pycharm 5 using either the terminal plugin or the python console.  The terminal also picks up that I'm using zsh and prezto and works will all those features just like in the normal terminal.

Comment: The question is specifically pdb / ipdb. "Normal" terminal works just fine. Thus, the question. Can you confirm the up arrow works in a software using `readline` based prompt in a `Run` console window?